# using jqueryui modal dialog makes the font smaller and pushes the main div down

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

We're trying to implement the jqueryui modal dialog. However, it seems that when we do this, something in the styles are making the fonts smaller and pushing the main div down a little.

Here is the before adding the modal dialog:

http://daldevwebcms2:90/frog/partnerportal/update-my-company-information.html

Here is after we add the modal dialog:

http://daldevwebcms2:90/frog/partnerportal/update-my-company-information2.html

Does anyone know how we can remedy this?

Thanks for your help.

umbre

Comment: It appears that your urls are not on the public web, so there's no way to provide feedback on them. That said, it's likely you need to reconcile the conflicts between the jQuery UI themes and your own styling.

Comment: Thanks artlung! I was able to work it out. It was indeed a conflict between our own styling and the jquery ui theme. Thanks!